# Image-text change color when hover an image

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have an image and some text. What I want is when hover the image, the image will have opacity and the color of the text change. My problem is when the image has opacity, the text also have opacity so it seem I can't see the text. How can I solve that problem? **Note:** I use image instead of background-image in this case because of some problem, so just help me solve this with image. Thanks a lots!

This picture is exactly what I want: [image]

Here is my code

```css
.categories {
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.categories:hover {
  opacity: 35%;
  color: black;
}

.categories__text {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <div class="categories__child">
    <img alt="img" src="https://www.petcity.vn/media/news/923_gia_mua_ban_cho_phoc_soc_thukieng_12.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="categories__text">HERE IS THE TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the image and text styles:

```css
.categories {
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  width: 256px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.categories:hover {
  color: black;
}

.categories:hover img {
  opacity: 35%;
}

.categories__text {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
  <div class="categories__child">
    <img alt="img" src="https://www.petcity.vn/media/news/923_gia_mua_ban_cho_phoc_soc_thukieng_12.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="categories__text">HERE IS THE TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I want.